# Converting Oracle Forms Package as an Oracle DB Package

Tags: oracle, package, oracleforms

My team is migrating an Oracle Form and Reports-based system into Java/Grails system. Since the destination programming language is very different from the source language, we cannot change the fact that there is a 100% recoding to be done. Some stored procedures are short, converting them is easy.

I stumble across a very important module with the name "End of Day (EOD) Batch Process". Inside this oracle form is a huge package with 4369 lines of pure PL/SQL code. I am becoming anxious on converting this batch process. Is there any way to move this package to our database? Aside from the actual batch process underlying this package, there are also form-specific functions inside that are needed to be considered on the conversion (`set_application_property()`, `:b_main.ctrl_something := 'X'` and `ADD_GROUP_COLUMN()`).

Does removing this form specific functions enough for the conversion? Or is it really not possible to convert this form package into database package?

Comment: What is important is what that code does to your data, based on parameters passed to it from the forms application. So the aim is to capture that code in a packaged procedure and call it with the necessary parameters from your new application.